# Angular 12 Components without Navigation

Tags: angular

We are doing a POC of using modern Angular with JSF.

In the POC, we created a simple angular application, with one component that just prints out a message (the AlertComponent) and another one (GreetingComponent) which does something else but not relevant here.

We want to use these components in a JSF app without affecting JSF navigation, but I can't avoid the angular controller to change the location, and when I clone the index.html into index2.html still the index.html is loaded.

[image]

This is the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Server Test</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<h1>index.html</h1> <!-- index2.html in index2.html -->
  <my-alert alfa="beta"> </my-alert>
  <!-- <my-greeting></my-greeting> -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

//import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert/alert.component';
import { GreetingComponent } from './greeting/greeting.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    GreetingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
    //,AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  //bootstrap: [AppComponent,GreetingComponent,AlertComponent]
  entryComponents: [AlertComponent,GreetingComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    customElements.define('my-alert', createCustomElement(AlertComponent, {
      injector: this.injector
    }));
    customElements.define('my-greeting', createCustomElement(GreetingComponent, {
      injector: this.injector
    }));
  }
}
```

Any other info required please let me know and thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: You probably want to try a production build on an actual webserver. This is de dev server which redirects everything to index.html

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne . I tried now with --prod / --configuration production and same result. I also called enableProdMode() in main.ts. Same result so far :(

Comment: Actually I took the dist into the web server, cloned the index / index2 xhtml and translated to the strict XHTML and this time worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by cloning the page in dist folder, after ng build, deploying in a web server. Running ng serve --prod did not prevent this behavior in my tests.